# How to show display name in top right of GSuite Gmail just like normal Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

[image: Display at gmail account name displayed and profile picture shown]

Displays name at Gmail account name **displayed**

[image]

Name **not** **displayed** at GSuite Gmail account in top right.

I went to account to personal info and there I have the name Jaswir FeatherHatGames.

Comment: did you click on that "change" on that green J?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell you exactly what to do but I can suggest you to chek some settings in your Gmail acount, go to settings > Account and check on "send mail as" if you have your name setup with your email address.

Another option is to check myaccount.google.com and look for personal information to see if you have your name setup, since, as far as I know there is no option to disable this on the Admin Console.

last but not least check the admin.google.com > users and make sure you have name and last name assigned, however, I don't think this will be since it is a required field, otherwise I would suggest to contact G Suite Support. I hope that helps, greetings.